# how to parse " Remote " xml file using jquery/ajex for phonegap?

Tags: jquery, android, html, cordova

Any idea about how to parse a remote XML file using jQuery/AJAX for PhoneGap?
Or any PhoneGap code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you would just use a run of the mill `XMLHttpRequest` or assuming ajax then `$.ajax()`. Nothing special should be required. Phone gap (provided it is set up properly) can make cross domain calls. Just make sure your android application permissions are set.