# how to parse remote xml file with javascript/jQuery and phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, ajax, cordova

For phonegap development:

1. is it possible to fetch remote data for phonegape?
2. is it possible to fetch remote json/xml file using ajax/jquery ?
3. XmlHttpRequest can fetch remote xml file ?

also any suggestion for it or important link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax works no different that it does else where execept that cross domain calls are ok with phonegap, 
[see my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252312/how-to-parse-remote-xml-file-using-jquery-ajex-for-phonegap/6283358#6283358)

Example of jquery ajax call @ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ 
Parsing xml with javascript @ http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

[Example of native javascript call](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call#Creating_XMLHttpRequest_Objects)

Ref from phonegap about ajax 
(see question:

[Q. I want to create an application for phonegap to access externally deployed web services via AJAX. How can i resolve the issue with the cross-domain security policy of XmlHttpRequest?)](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494770/FAQ)

True to life example on this site

This should be enough to get you started.
Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: thanks a lot for all the information link and example, now i am clear about this