# internet permission on jquery-android app

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

i made a small app (with jquery and phonegap on Eclipse).
Inside this app I use some ajax to call a xml file.

On some device the internet permission does not work (for example Nexus S, rom non-stock rasbeanjelly, Samsung S3, android 4.1 jellybean). 
On others, it goes perfectly.

I used this permission in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I tried also adding this in the MainActivity (to avoid problem with slow connection):

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
```

Maybe it is not enough for every device or android version?

I used phonegap also to do the iOS version app, I got the same problem (but i tried only on the simulator).

Comment: Is the xml file on the device or remote?

Comment: Remote (that's the reason i ask the internet permission)

Comment: Can never be too sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261335/how-to-parse-remote-xml-file-with-javascript-jquery-and-phonegap

Comment: Thank you, I'll give a look to those manuals. 
After that, some real experience on the issue?

Comment: Every PG Android app needs the INTERNET permission do not remove it.